# How to split to new page when isIgnorePagination?

Tags: jasper-reports

Using Jaspersoft studio 6.2.

A main report with detail and summary bands. A sub report in the summary band of the main report. The main report itself (when without the subreport) will split into two pages, so I checked `isIgnorePagination` and the main report (when without subreport) comes out as single page.

The subreport itself split to 9 pages by default, when I checked `isIgnorePagination` it comes out as one single page. Fine. When I put the subreport in the main report with all the settings above, it comes out as one single page. How can I make the main report in one page and subreport in another page (so two pages in total)?

**EDIT**

Tried **break** component, it works but there is still a problem. The page height of the main report has to be set to be big enough to include both main report and subreport, otherwise there will be more than 2 pages, but that will leave too much blank at the bottom of the main report. Below is an example to show what I meant.

**main report**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
    <!-- 2016-04-26T16:13:43 -->
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test11" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ce9d78e1-7194-4754-aaf9-93e871d2a5cf">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="datamart"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select 1 as a
    union all select 2 as a]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="a" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <variable name="Total" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
            <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{a}]]></variableExpression>
        </variable>
        <background>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </background>
        <columnHeader>
            <band height="50">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="54" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="e9116c0f-c827-4cb3-95d1-9155f4be7cb7"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[a]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </columnHeader>
        <detail>
            <band height="49" splitType="Stretch">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="50" y="10" width="100" height="30" uuid="79fa53fa-48e2-43d0-96a4-0cda54e95c25"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{a}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </detail>
        <summary>
            <band height="297" splitType="Stretch">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="52" y="16" width="100" height="30" backcolor="#C4E5F6" uuid="2a393151-947e-4f1d-ab24-e456ce56bd19"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Total}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="62" y="97" width="200" height="200" uuid="b342cbae-597b-4ca5-b00d-3a4d047910f8"/>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["test12.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
                <break>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="60" width="619" height="1" uuid="ccc2155d-6a2e-4c23-a972-88bb871cb17d"/>
                </break>
            </band>
        </summary>
    </jasperReport>
```

**sub report**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
    <!-- 2016-04-26T16:14:10 -->
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test12" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3601f813-f6da-4105-a4d8-5c1ee1dd54d4">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="datamart"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select 10 as col 
    union all select 20  as col]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="col" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <variable name="total" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
            <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{col}]]></variableExpression>
        </variable>
        <background>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </background>
        <columnHeader>
            <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="73" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="5f2cfa26-c7ab-413e-94cf-80c1f1b288eb"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[col]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </columnHeader>
        <detail>
            <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="73" y="90" width="100" height="30" uuid="3af983fb-00e2-4bb9-9e91-2d2214ca95d7"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{col}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </detail>
        <summary>
            <band height="49" splitType="Stretch">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="74" y="19" width="100" height="30" backcolor="#FFCC33" uuid="b333fb92-8aa8-4f00-9a1a-db24657d5521"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{total}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </summary>
    </jasperReport>
```

There is a break in the main report, this works fine, 2 pages one for the main report and one for the sub report, but the main report leaves too much blank at the bottom, if I reduce the height of the main report (e.g. to 400 pixel), there will be more than 2 pages. Is it possible to get just 2 pages without too much blank?

Comment: Use the title band, detail band (main report)  and summary band (subreport) with attribute isSummaryNewPage="true" and you have two pages or use the break component. seems strange you need to use IgnorePagination , can you create a [mcve]

Comment: Hi I am new to jasper report. Where can i find the isSummaryNewPage or break component?

Comment: isSummaryNewPage is an attrbiute on the jasperReport tag (you find it in properties if you select the root structure tag). break is a component that includes a page break or column break (you find it in the palette if you are using IDE)

Comment: Updated. Added an example, the break component works, but there is still a problem.

Comment: You need different page height on the different pages?

Comment: yes, one report fits in its own page in its own size, is this not normal in Jasper? Sorry, I was from SSRS, this is never a problem there.

Comment: Then yes you need to use  IgnorePagination, set small height as possibile and use the break component. Is it normal, depends on export, in pdf its not normal, normal would be A4...

Comment: I tried adding IgnorePagination on the main report and there is already a beak before the subreport, but it comes out as one single report. Forgot to mention the reason for different page size for different report is mainly for viewing the report online (Jasper server), so no printing concern. We will at most output to excel, that's no issue there either.

Comment: Ok I have answered so you can see how it is achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve different size for each page you need to use the attribute, `isIgnorePagination="true"` on the `jasperReport` tag.

When `isIgnorePagination` is true the **break** element is **ignored by default** you need to enabled it by setting this property [net.sf.jasperreports.page.break.no.pagination](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.page.break.no.pagination) to `apply`

> **ignore** - page breaks are ignored in non paginated reports. (default) 
> **apply** -
>    page breaks are honoured in non paginated reports.

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.page.break.no.pagination" value="apply"/>
```

This will enable the break component and you can **manuale break to new page** using

```
<break> 
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="1" uuid="604c65b5-1127-4874-a63c-9b1a98dbf25c"/>
</break>
```

Comment: That setting does generate two separate pages. But it seems the main or first report will adjust the size to accommodate the subreport in the summary band. So the main report still has huge blank spaces. My example is not obvious, but you can easily test it by changing the query in the subreport to generate a lot more detail data so you will be able to see the issue.

Comment: You have set isIgnorePagination="true" and the pageHeight to a minimum?

Comment: yes, isIgnorePagination="true" , for main height = 250, subreport height = 400, both are at a minimum (lower then it will report error that it can't fit in page height ), however the first report displays  a page of maybe several thousand pixel of height with huge blanks beneath the report. The reason is subreport now shows  a lot more details (remember I have changed the query). You can test it, the query is generic.